# (LDA) Topic Modeling: eliminate Junktopics through normalization

Tags: normalization, exploratory-data-analysis, topic-models

**Question:** *Is it reasonable to normalize topics to eliminate junk-topics and get a better distinction of document-relations?*

I used the MALLET-LDA Java-library to estimate a ParallelTopicModel with 4000 iterations and K=50 topics over 2050 Files. Then I calculated the cosine similarity for all documents and exported the resulting matrix as the following graphic. Saturation is proportional to cosine-similarity and the color relates to the most relevant topic connecting both documents.

[image]

As you can see, the purple topic spreads over the whole text-corpus. After normalizing all topics to 1 and recalculating the document-similarities, the contrast gets higher while the relevant topics (color) stay mostly the same.

[image]

The refutation of this approach is that not every topic is equally present. In the case of document-exploration / recommendation the elimination of junk topics seems more relevant than the exact quantity of every topic.